# Javascript change icon

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, icons

I try to change the icon with select element. I have made it with 2 values, but now I need 3.

Any idea what is wrong with this code?

```
var icon = document.getElementById.("marker-icon"); 
    if (type == 1) {  
        marker-icon.src = "images/icon1.png";
    } else if (type == 2) {
        marker-icon.src = "images/icon2.png";
    } else if (type == 3) {
        marker-icon.src = "images/icon3.png";
}
```

This code is for 2 values and it works fine.

```
var icon = (type == 1) ? "images/icon1.png" : "images/icon2.png";
```

Comment: You have a `.` after `getElementById`

Comment: You need to use the icon variable to set the src, not `marker-icon` also why not use type to set the new icon. Example `icon.src='images/icon'+type+'.png';` Can you show where `marker-icon` is defined and show the html to go with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use switch case syntax.

```
switch (type) {
    case 1:
        var icon =  "images/icon1.png";
        break;
    case 2:
        var icon =  "images/icon2.png";
        break;
    case 3:
        var icon =  "images/icon3.png";
        break;
    default:
        //default code block
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var icon = document.getElementById("marker-icon"); 
if (type == 1) {  
    icon.src = "images/icon1.png";
} else if (type == 2) {
    icon.src = "images/icon2.png";
} else if (type == 3) {
    icon.src = "images/icon3.png";
}
```

There was an extra `.` after the `getElementById` and you were using `marker-icon` instead of `icon`. (I am assuming that `marker-icon` is the `id` of an `img` tag.)

Answer (score 0):

It works with that :

```
var icon = document.getElementById("icon"); 
    if (type == 1) {  
        icon = "images/icon1.png";
    } else if (type == 2) {
        icon = "images/icon2.png";
    } else if (type == 3) {
        icon = "images/icon3.png";
    }
```

Thanks for all! ^^